# How to make one cannon instead of multiple?

Tags: python, graphics

I am currently in the process of making a new cannon game. How can I make it so that there is just one cannon, on the bottom left hand of the screen?

```
from graphics import *
from math import sqrt
from math import trunc

def PinR(p,r):
    if p.getX()>=r.getP1().getX() and p.getX()<=r.getP2().getX()and p.getY()>=r.getP1().getY() and p.getY()<=r.getP2().getY():
       return True;
    else:
        return False;
def distance(p1,p2):
    dx=p1.getX()-p2.getX();
    dy=p1.getY()-p2.getY();
    dist=sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
    return dist;

#parameter
FieldWidth=700;
FieldHeight=700;
GroundDepth=75;
BallSize=10;
OriginalSpeed=4;
FieldBackground="brown";
FieldBorder="brown";
tickLength=800000;
buttonSize=8;

#   number of cannons and balls
numBalls=4;
#   initial cannon power
explosionStrength=30;
#   intial gravitational constant
g=1;
#   clock tick delay
delay=0.05;


#Create field
Field=GraphWin("B",FieldWidth,FieldHeight);
Field.setBackground(FieldBackground);

#set of balls
spacing=FieldWidth/(numBalls);
ball=[];
for b in range (0,numBalls):
    newball=Circle(Point(spacing*b+spacing//2,FieldHeight-GroundDepth),BallSize);
    newball.setFill("black");
    newball.draw(Field);
    ball.append(newball);

#cannon
cannon=[]
for c in range (0,numBalls):
    newCannon=Rectangle(Point(spacing*c+spacing//2-BallSize,FieldHeight-GroundDepth-BallSize*5),
                        Point(spacing*c+spacing//2+BallSize,FieldHeight-GroundDepth+BallSize));
    newCannon.setFill("black");
    newCannon.draw(Field);
    cannon.append(newCannon);

#set of button groups (fire, powerup, powerdown)
fire=[];
for f in range (0,numBalls):
    newbutton=Rectangle(Point(spacing*f+spacing//2-buttonSize//2,FieldHeight-GroundDepth-BallSize),
                        Point(spacing*f+spacing//2+buttonSize//2,FieldHeight-GroundDepth-BallSize+buttonSize));
    newbutton.setFill("red");
    newbutton.draw(Field);
    fire.append(newbutton);

#wall

#target(red,white,red,white)
balldistance=20;
ball1=Circle(Point(FieldWidth//2-20,FieldHeight//2+20),BallSize);
ball1.setFill("red");
ball1.draw(Field);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get 4 cannons is that you're doing this:

```
for c in range (0,numBalls):
```

… where `numBalls` is 4, and you create a new cannon each time through the loop.

Presumably with only 1 cannon you also only want one cannon ball and one shot, so just set `numBalls = 1` instead of `numBalls = 4`.

However, it might make more sense to simplify the program while you're at it. Replace the lists of 4 cannons with a single cannon, get rid of the loop, do the same for the 4 balls, etc. Then you can also simplify the layout rules—no need for a `spacing` variable to configure how far apart the cannons are if there's only 1 of them. And so on. This might make it easier for you to understand how the program works—and figuring out how to simplify it might similarly be beneficial on its own.

---

And if you want to change its position, that's being set in this line:

```
newCannon=Rectangle(Point(spacing*c+spacing//2-BallSize,FieldHeight-GroundDepth-BallSize*5),
                    Point(spacing*c+spacing//2+BallSize,FieldHeight-GroundDepth+BallSize));
```

So, you can tweak the various constants (which all seem to have pretty reasonable names) to get the result you want—or, of course, just hardcode the position you want instead of calculating it.

Comment: Sometimes it's still a good idea to leave the single canon in a list. For example if your render/update/collision functions work with lists of lists.

Comment: @gnibbler: Sure, and it also means if you later decide you want 2 cannons it's easier to change. But I think the simplification is worth doing in this case, at least as an exercise, if not to keep things that way.

Comment: That did work, However it forms in the bottom middle of the screen. Would you know how to move it over to the left bottom corner?

Comment: @NickFunchion: I already explained that in the last part. You've got this complicated expression (in this case, the `spacing*c+spacing//2` +/- `BallSize` parts). Either replace the expression with something different (like just `2 * BallSize`) or tweak the `spacing` constant to match what you want.